# c++ syntax error on an static method

Tags: c++, node.js

I have the following code :

```
class v8NMatch : public V8Wrap<Match, v8NMatch>
{
public:
    static v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> s_ct;
    static void Init(v8::Handle<v8::Object> target);
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> IsSuccess(Arguments& args);

    v8NMatch(const v8::Arguments& args);

};
```

It tells me I have a syntax error at the identifier Arguments.
If I put the const keyword before Arguments, I have 2 errors :

> missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> syntax error : missing ',' before '&'

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IsSuccess is defined without the v8::Arguments.

Comment: I did actually make a using of v8. However, since there was some conflicts with my class names, I prefixed by the namespace just to be sure. I tried adding it on Arguments, but same result.

Comment: @NicolasPenin: What line of code is the specific error pointing to?

Comment: the line where the static method IsSuccess is declared

Comment: My mistake, I had 2 classes, and only the first one was causing this error, but I changed it on the second one. Changing it on the first one did the trick. Thanks.